# Batch Script: Identifying the latest file with incrementing file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Can someone help me with handling the specific scenario explained below using windows batch script.

We have a shared folder, which is used by a third party application tool (OBIEE) as a version controlled folder. In this folder the tool creates backup files with incrementing extension numbers.

**For example**: If we have a code file **`Projects.rpd`**, the first time we checkout this file, the tool creates **`Projects.000`** as a backup file. The next time it will be `Projects.001`, then `Projects.002` and so on.

In the batch script, I need to get the file name of the latest backup file. In this example, `Projects.002`

I cannot go for the file with the latest timestamp, since the latest backup (`Projects.002`), the latest code file (`Projects.rpd`) and another control file will always have the same timestamp.

**How can I identify the latest backup file in this scenario**?

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "latest="
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\projects.*"') DO (
 IF /i "%%~xa" leq ".A" SET "latest=%%~xa"
)
ECHO %latest%
SET "latest=%latest:~1%"
ECHO latest is "%latest%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

It would have been really helpful to post the name of the "other control file." I'm forced to assume it's called `report.somethingelse` where `somethingelse` is alphabetic.

Comment: Instead of the `IF` statement, I'd be more comfortable with a regex match on an extension with 3 decimal digits, e.g. `'DIR /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\projects.*" ^| findstr /r "\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]$"'`. What do you think?

Comment: However you feel. Not enough information about the disposition of the `project.*` files, but your mod would work, albeit a little slower because of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert this line in your Batch file:

```
for /L %%i in (0,1,9) do for %%a in (Projects.%%i*) do set "latestBackup=%%a"
```